# NodeJS Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've been following a bunch of tutorials on how to do a little web-scraping in Node JS

(I'm a complete noob so any insight on a matter, no matter how basic, helps)

I've been trying to find a way to save my array 'urls' to a text file but have run into several issues- This is asynchronous because the link gathering takes time, and I can't really grasp how callbacks work in Node.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var links = [];

request('http://www.reddit.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title', '#siteTable').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            urls.push(url);
        });
        console.log(links);
    }
});
```

I was thinking of simply putting this entire 'section' on a timeout that would give it enough time to compile the list of links but I wanted to see what the cleaner and more proper way of doing it is.

Could anyone show me how I would use a callback for this so I could set up a print function to save the output afterwards?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: You could write a function which takes in your array then saves it to a file. Basically, replace `console.log(links)` with `saveLinks(links)` where `saveLinks` is the function you wrote.

Comment: Just run your code after you get the response.

Comment: Ok- I'll try these out- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good except for one mistake. You don't have an array called `urls` declared but you are then pushing to it. Just change `urls.push(url);` to `links.push(url);` so you have

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var links = [];

request('http://www.reddit.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title', '#siteTable').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            links.push(url);
        });
        console.log(links);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good catch! I was doing some last second manual replacing since I wanted to reference something later on as 'urls'. I ended up solving my issue with a timeout of 15 seconds on an additional write to text file function.

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. In general, using a setTimeout is usually a pretty hacky solution (not that I have never done it). So if you still have questions feel free